# AssertionError in nosetests

Tags: python, nosetests

When I start tests with

`nosetests --with-doctest --doctest-extension=txt`

I got this error.

> ```
> F
> ======================================================================
> FAIL: Doctest: README.txt
> ----------------------------------------------------------------------
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python2.6/doctest.py", line 2152, in runTest
>     raise self.failureException(self.format_failure(new.getvalue()))
> AssertionError: Failed doctest test for README.txt
>   File "/home/xralf/example/README.txt", line 0
> ```

How should I repair this error? Is it something bad with test (because it's line 0)

thank you

Comment: What does (the first few lines of) README.txt contain?

Comment: 1:=================
2:example
3:=================

Comment: Works for me: https://gist.github.com/1292571 (using similar header), so something else in the file is probably wrong. What does the first doctest in the file look like?

Comment: Thank you, I tested it and added line by line. There should be more whitespace in my `README.txt` (e.g. after import statement). Should I delete this or do you make an answer from it?

Comment: @xralf Answer your own question and select the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `README.txt` file there should be more whitespace, especially after the statements that don't return a value (like import statements).

```
=============
example
=============
>>> a = 3
>>> a - 1
2
>>> from sqlite3 import dbapi2 as sqlite

some text
```

Important is the space after import statement. Without it this won't work.

Comment: The answer would be more useful if you show a short example that reproduces your original problem, and then shows a corrected example that solves the problem.

Comment: Here's the relevant bits from the Python documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html#how-are-docstring-examples-recognized